# Key event in Corona

Tags: events, button, key, coronasdk

I'm new to Corona. Can I use a key on my PC keyboard for testing my game?
It's really uncomfortable to use the button on the simulator screen.
I've found this in the documentation:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/key/keyName.html

The D-Pad/Trackball key strings are: "up", "down", "left", "right", and "center".

What does it mean? It works only in Android simulator, or can I use these keys from PC keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

No.  These keys represent the physical and soft keys on Android devices.  They are not available on iOS or on the simulators but only on device.